# Sharepoint Document Library with metadata pulled from a joined list- is it possible without coding?

Tags: sharepoint, join, lookup

I'm using Sharepoint 2007 WSS

My team works on projects, each projects then involves a number of documents. I have found information on various Sharepoint sites and help pages about the two techniques of:

1) Creating metadata columns in a document library, then linking these to the document properties panel (e.g. in Word)

2) Joining (in the SQL sense) two Sharepoint lists on a common value (i.e. a lookup on an ID column). This produces a merged data view (albeit a really, really ugly one).

I was naively hoping it was possible to do the following:

[Argh, Stackoverflow has prevented me from posting an image here as a new user. You'll jst have to imagine my nice little drawing of the joined lists]

The idea is the user would create a new document, pick a project ID, and the document could then "see" all the additional items of project metadata.

However the Data View web part delivers a dumb tabulated list of text data, it's not a "live" Sharepoint library. Meanwhile a library can have a simgle lookup column (e.g. the Project ID) but I can't see how to populate the other columns in the library, these effectively need to do an "indirect lookup".

Am i asking too much? This seems to be a reasonable thing to attempt but at the moment i'm hitting a brick wall.

Comment: Can you migrate to SharePoint Foundation 2010?

Comment: sadly, that's not under my control. I've read that this might be possible in SP2010, but for the forseeable future i am stuck on WSS 2007 :-{

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to go for you is to create a webpart for creation documnet and then another one for viewing your documents. This way they will LOOK AS NICE AS YOU NEED and will be able to display exactly what you want.

So.
1) You create a library for your documents with a lookup column (and other fields)
2) you create a webpart that has a UI with all the fields from the document library (in edit mode) arranged as you want, a dropdown and readonly fields for your projects' information. Once the user chooses a value in the dropdown your webpart fetches all the data for the project and puts it to the readonly form fields on the UI. and when a user clicks "Save" you create a new document and populates its fields with data from the UI including the lookup field for the project. and the readonly form fields with project info do not get saved (since they are stored already in the projects list).
3) you create a webpart to display your documents (optionally you can craete also a webpart to display a list of docs with so called dependend lookup information) in the way you want. So the webpart will have all the fields from the documents library and all the needed fields from the projects list. this webpart will get the data from the doc library and will grab the project information from the projects list using the lookup column in the doc lib.

This is in brief. Plz let me know if you need more guidance.
Good luck!